# Allow unauthorized users from specific IP/Domain only for some directories using <location path="XXX"> tag in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have some folders in my ASP.Net applications which requires access without login. For that I have already setup this configurations in my web.config file

```
 <location path="XXXX">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Now I want to restrict the "path" to have anonymous/unauthorized access from one specific IP address or domain only. How do I setup this security configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <location path="XXXX">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                <clear/> 
                <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>  <!-- change ip here-->
             </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

**Note 1** : you will need the IP Secuity module installed.  Can be found here: Windows Features/Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services/Security/IP Security

**Note 2**: you will need to allow ipSecurity to be overridden in your **applicationHost.config**.  You can change this by changing the ipSecurity section.

e.g.

`<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`

The applicationHost.config file is usually found here: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

If you don't have access to this file then you wont be able to do it without asking the server admin.

Comment: Great !! I read about <ipsecurity> but didn't override section config in applicationhost.config file. Thank you for pointing out in detail.